# How do I calibrate two displays to the same color? (LCD, LED backlight and CCFL backlight)

Tags: color-management, display-calibration, colorimeter

I've got two displays. One is approximately six years old: Fujitsu P24-5 ECO (LCD/IPS, CCFL backlight), the other one is a DELL U2412M (LCD/IPS, LED backlight).

I've tried to color calibrate both displays (LinuxMint, dispcalGUI, 6500K, 140cdm²) with three different colorimeters that I could access (an old-ish Pantone Huey Pro, a brand-new Colormunki Smile and my very own brand-new Colormunki Display).

With all three colorimeters (and a handfull of different settings concerning the profile type etc, including color correction matrices for the Dell Display with the Colormunki Display - couldn't find correction matrices for the Fujitsu) the results were essentially the same: Checking with the eye the white point seemed to be very close for both displays, as were brightness etc. But on closer Inspection the Fujitsu does have a slight red-ish tint (compared to the DELL, that doesn't yet imply which one is closer to the "real" colour). This is almost not noticable (i. e. only with side-by-side comparison) for sunsets or brown leafs, but it's a big difference for lighter skin tones (giving someone a sunburn only on the Fujitsu Display).

On yet closer inspection the TRC curves of the display profiles (that I can view from the colour panel in my system settings) look a bit different:

[image: Dell TRC curve]

The Dell TRC curve has all three colors of RGB neatly on top of each other.

[image: Fujitsu TRC curve]

The Fujitsu TRC curve seems to indicate that red is somehow intensified.

That said, I don't know the real meaning of this curve. Especially I don't under stand why, if its meaning should be "right, the Fujitsu is tinted red" why this wasn't compensated through the display. Or could it be the other way round: Red is intensified by the profile because the instrument read a smaller brightness for red and wants to compensate for that.

But then, if the latter should be the case: I did calibrate the displays with the colorimeters before each profiling, so the colors brightnesses at maximum brightness should have been essentially the same to begin with - at least that was the colorimeter readout during calibration.

Could it be, that the instruments read the three colors differently during calibration vs. profiling?

I really don't understand what's happening here. My expectation would have been two essentially equal color reproductions on both displays.

Would it help to buy a spectrometer (e.g. Colormunki Photo)? Or what else could I do?

EDIT: MirekE suggested in an answer to try and set the standard observer on dispcal (-Q 1964_10). Unfortunately this doesn't change much and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: As it turns out, the effect I was seeing was created by some weird color management behaviour in darktable. Even though `darktable-cmstest` reported for both screens that "the X atom and colord returned the same profile", the weird behaviour went away with a configuration setting: I've now set the GUI option how darktable locates the color profile from all to Colord, and everything works fine, so far. :-)

I achieved this thanks to help on the [dispcalgui-users](http://sourceforge.net/p/dispcalgui/mailman/dispcalgui-users/thread/5543A8B9.5040406%40Fingerle.org/#msg34075626) ML. (Follow the [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/dispcalgui/mailman/dispcalgui-users/thread/5543A8B9.5040406%40Fingerle.org/#msg34075626) for the thread there.

Answer (score 1):

In DispCalcGui go to Options->Set additional command line arguments... New dialog box should open with a list of tools. In the box that says "dispcal" enter **-Q 1964_10** and see if it makes any difference. This parameter sets standard observer to CIE 1964 10º, which reportedly improves the results when matching multiple displays with different backlighting technology.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try that out and come back with the results.

Comment: Ok. I've tried it out, but the outcome is essentially the same. Even though this answer didn't help me, I sincerely hope, that it will help someday someone else in a similar situation (hence the upvote), but for my situation I still need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'v get a Spyder4Elite where you can choose an option to match multiple screens called "StudioMatch". Don't you have the same with the ColorMunki software? I suppose it's named differently.

Comment: I'm on Linux (so the vendor software won't run) with dispcalGUI. I'm unaware of any such option in dispcalGUI nor the underlying command line programs. :-(

Comment: Unfortunately not. Give it a try calibrating to the identical settings for all of them.

Comment: Well, yes, for all I know, that's what I did.