# If I calibrate two different monitors should I expect the two displays to look the same afterward?

Tags: color-management

I have a 2012 Macbook Pro and a Dell U2417H monitor.  Using the software that came with Spyder Pro 4 the monitors ended up looking radically different in color temperature.  The Macbook Pro display was much, much cooler than the Dell.

I calibrated again, but this time using the Dispcal+Argyll tools (using the Spyder 4 input device).  The two displays are much closer, but still different (the Dell is still warmer).

Note that I'm not a color profile pro. I just accepted the defaults when using both toolsets.

Am I expecting too much?  Should I expect them to look the same?

Comment: Is the Dell attached to the same 2012 Macbook Pro or another computer? What "preset mode" is the internal menu on the Dell set to? (Standard, Multimedia, Movie, Game, Text, Warm, Cool, or Custom Color?)

Comment: *I just accepted the defaults when using both toolsets.* Which defaults? The ones in the Dell's internal menu? The one's in the Mac's display settings? The ones in each software?

Comment: I'm guessing this one has more to do with the Dell being set to an 'auto correct' mode than anything else. The suggested duplicates are more applicable to minor differences in gamut than what the OP is describing here.

Comment: Yes, to all the questions.  I set each display to its defaults (Standard on the Dell) (neither has RGB settings).  The Dell was attached to the Macbook. And I used the default setting for both calibration softwares.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  I went to the duped question.  My answers were in [How to calibrate 2 monitors identically?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/how-to-calibrate-2-monitors-identically).

Comment: The Dell has RGB settings under 'Custom Color' and allows manual settings that won't be changed by the monitor based on the content of the signal it is receiving. The best way to calibrate/profile a monitor is to get it as close as possible using the RGB adjustments on the monitor (while measuring with the colorimeter) before doing the automatic profiling.